# How to download a m3u8 video file chunk by chunk?

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I'm not sure whether this question is eligible to ask in this forum. I just want to know how the video streaming applications like,

- [Hotstar](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/hotstar/id934459219?mt=8)
- [Youtube](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/youtube/id544007664?mt=8)
- [Spuul](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/spuul-free-indian-movies-tv/id524623291?mt=8)

and all developed a downloading manager which handle a video downloading process smoothy. How can we develop the same in my application? What are all the things i need to check for developing this? How should i develop it properly?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There now exists a Chrome extension which unites segments from m3u8 list and combines them in a video which then is saved to your computer.

Here's the link [HLS Video Saver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hds-hls-video-downloader/gelfgldejnhgpjcbnfpkglhpelajafao).

Answer (score 0):

Your best shot is HLS. Segment your video file on server side with lets say
[apple segmenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html). Then create m3u8 playlist with these files. Next open the playlist file with the media player of your choice.